# Настройка переадресации ModRewrite .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Всем привет. Столкнулся с ерундой и никак не могу понять почему не работает. Есть адрес `www.example.com`, есть каталог `section`, нужно чтобы при обращении к адресу `www.example.com/section(.*)$` происходил внутренний редирект (без смены адреса в браузре) на `www.example.com$1`, однако при прямом обращении через браузер к `www.example.com` должно возвращаться `404`.

Я сделал так:
Создал каталог `section` в него поместил `.htaccess` с содержимым

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

В корне хоста поместил `.htaccess` с содержимым

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/section [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

Однако проверка `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/section [NC]` не проходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте оставить только в корне сайта `.htaccess` такого содержания:

```
RewriteEngine On

# если обращение к папке section,
# то откинуть папку
RewriteRule ^section/(.*)$ $1 [L,QSA]

# если не было ни одноо редиректа,
# то 404 ошибка
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```